# How to properly index a NumPy array with stored images?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to understand the output of `cv2.imread`.

I have loaded PNG images into a NumPy array as grayscale. I think I have succeeded in doing so. I understand that `imagesList[0]` gives me a NumPy array of the first image, however I don't understand what the numbers within `imagesList[0][1]` correspond to. In that same vein of questioning, what would the numbers correspond to an `(m, n, 3)` image?

```
# cv2 is openCV, an image processing package 
import numpy as np
import cv2

#start and ending slice
startSlice = 753
endSlice = 823

# each image array will be stored in the list.
# imagesList[0] = first slice, imagesList[-1] = last slice
imagesList = []

# reading the image as a greyscale array, and storing into imagesList
for i in range(startSlice,endSlice+1):
  fileName = "/somefilelocation"+'{0:04}'.format(i)+'.png'
  im = cv2.imread(fileName,0)
  imagesList.append(im)
  print(fileName)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop, you read in several images with `cv2.imread`, which all will be stored as NumPy arrays in your list `imagesList`:

- First level of indexing in `imagesList`, e.g. `imagesList[0]` will
  give you the corresponding (whole) image (NumPy array).
- Second level of indexing, e.g. `imagesList[0][1]` will
  give you the corresponding row in that image (NumPy array).
- Third level of indexing, e.g. `imagesList[0][1][2]` will
  give you the corresponding row and column (i.e. an actual pixel) in that image (NumPy array).
- Fourth level of indexing, e.g. `imagesList[0][1][2][0]` will
  give you the corresponding color value (blue, green or red) at the corresponding row and column (pixel) in that image (NumPy array). Attention: Fourth indices > 0 are only applicable to color images!

Let's have a small test:

```py
import cv2

# Read image.
image = cv2.imread('ithMo.png')

# Store image as color and grayscale in list.
imagesList = [image, cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)]

# Access first image (color)
print('whole image (BGR values): \n\n', imagesList[0], '\n')
print('second row of image (BGR values): \n\n', imagesList[0][1], '\n')
print('second row, third column of image (BGR value): \n\n', imagesList[0][1][2], '\n')
print('second row, third column of image, first channel (B value): \n\n', imagesList[0][1][2][0], '\n')

# Access second image (gray)
print('whole image (gray values): \n\n', imagesList[1], '\n')
print('second row of image (gray values): \n\n', imagesList[1][1], '\n')
print('second row, third column of image (gray value): \n\n', imagesList[1][1][2], '\n')
```

This image

[image: Input]

is stored as color and grayscale in `imagesList`, and the aforementioned levels of indexing are tested.

I tried to shorten the output as much as possible, and marked the important parts:

```
whole image (BGR values): 

 [[[239 124  63]
  [239 123  65]
  [240 124  64]
  ...

 [[238 128  74]         <<< Here begins the second row
  [239 122  66]
  [239 125  68]
  ...

 [[244 200 173]
  [239 134  86]
  [240 132  80]
  ...


second row of image (BGR values): 

 [[238 128  74]
 [239 122  66]
 [239 125  68]          <<< Here is the third column
 ...

second row, third column of image (BGR value): 

 [239 125  68]          

second row, third column of image, first channel (B value): 

 239 

whole image (gray values): 

 [[119 119 119 ... 231 230 228]
 [124 119 121 ... 229 228 228]      <<< Here begins the second row
 [197 132 129 ... 227 228 230]
 ...
 [ 49  56  54 ...  52  53  54]
 [ 45  48  55 ...  51  54  50]
 [ 57  56  55 ...  48  48  46]] 

second row of image (gray values): 

 [124 119 121 126 143 119 120 123 133 128 122 117 117 115 116 120 157 171
 162 178 173 177 173 137 144 158 124 116 117 117 116 123 131 132 122 127
 141 136 127 126 130 148 168 162 163 137 132 124 118 121 120 121 120 118
 119 119 121 121 125 125 127 129 127 128 130 132 132 130 129 129 135 132
 134 135 135 133 136 143 149 129 131 132 132 135 138 139 139 140 148 154
 157 185 211 222 224 223 221 215 209 208 212 221 230 235 237 238 235 230
 211 166 159 164 169 173 179 186 190 197 211 217 211 212 211 212 217 215
 209 201 202 194 193 188 184 183 185 188 182 183 173 167 159 152 147 142
 139 138 137 137 132 125 123 124 124 122 121 122 126 130 132 135 141 140
 145 148 151 148 149 151 160 159 158 154 157 160 158 166 166 165 162 156
 165 178 180 169 172 169 173 193 188 181 172 165 164 177 139 157 176 177
 157 131 132 131 145 146 140 127 132 150 195 205 224 239 242 243 242 242
 242 242 241 243 243 241 244 244 244 245 246 245 245 245 245 245 244 242
 242 243 243 243 243 244 241 241 242 238 226 216 229 234 238 235 239 240
 240 240 240 240 242 242 242 243 242 242 242 241 242 241 241 240 240 241
 241 240 241 242 242 242 242 242 242 242 240 240 239 238 236 235 234 234
 234 235 236 236 235 233 231 232 230 229 228 228] 

second row, third column of image (gray value): 

 121
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @NoahBastola Nice to hear that. If that answer was helpful to you, feel free to upvote and/or accept it, see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)